# Separate legend by facet for geom_segment and geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am interested in creating a figure akin to the below, which has a separate legend entry for each of four components: two `geom_segment` and two `geom_point`, which are grouped according to some facet (corresponding to the color).

[image: figure]

Here is a sample dataset, and some initial code.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
y <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
z <- c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30)
s <- c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
t <- c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
n <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
       "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
df <- cbind(rbind(data.frame(x = x, y = y, s = s), data.frame(x = x, y = z, s = t)), n)

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = n)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "gray64")) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 0, xend = 10, y = 10, yend = 10), color = "blue", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 0, xend = 10, y = 20, yend = 20), color = "gray64", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = dplyr::filter(df, n == "A"), mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, shape = "Label A.1"), color = "gray") + 
    geom_point(data = dplyr::filter(df, n == "B"), mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, shape = "Label B.1"), color = "blue") + 
    geom_line(data = dplyr::filter(df, n == "A"), mapping = aes(x = x, y = s, color = "Label A.2")) + 
    geom_line(data = dplyr::filter(df, n == "B"), mapping = aes(x = x, y = s, color = "Label B.2")) + 
    scale_shape_manual(name = NULL, values = c(19, 19)) + 
    scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c("Label A.2" = "gray", "Label B.2" = "blue")) + 
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("Label A.1" = "gray", "Label B.1" = "blue"))))
```

`ggplot2` doesn't seem to like separating legends (I suppose it does make the plot more complicated). In this solution, we add each layer separately, controlling the legend using shape (which we later set to `19`, the default filled-in circle) and color aesthetics. In the last line, we make sure the colors of the shape layer are correct (try the code without the last line to see what it does!).

I also don't think "facet" is used correctly in your question. Generally, [facets are like subplots](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).